# Box-Api- Connection refused while fetching accessToken

Tags: oauth, box-api

We are experiencing sporadic "connection refused" errors when trying to connect to https://api.box.com for getting accessToken and refreshToken. We are using apache amber client api to connect to box . The connectivity issue happens at random . is there a possibility that api.box.com . The flow of our OAUTH process is typical

## INITIAL TOKEN FETCH

1. Hit the appurl that redirects to api.box.com/oauth2/authorize
2. redirect to Box login page 
   3.After successful authentication , Box redirects to AUTH_REDIRECT_URI configured in the request along with the authorization code
3. Our app sends a request to get api.box.com/oauth2/token to get the accessToken and refreshtoken

## REFRESHTOKEN

5.After which, for  every request  to our app makes a request to 
api.box.com/oauth2/token to get the new accessToken and refreshtoken

Is there any Box customer support that we can contact as the issue happens in our  production environment.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

You can totally contact Box support by either emailing api@box.com, or following the link on the lower right side of your box account menu.